# How do I use generics in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I have the following code:

```
Public Shared Function GetListAsString(ByVal data As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim retVal As String = "| "
    For Each obj As String In data
        retVal = retVal + obj.ToString() + " |"
    Next
    Return retVal
End Function
```

It converts a List to a printable String. Right now it is set up to work with *just* Lists. I feel as if it should be able to work with any type of Collection. I am new to Collections and generics. When I attempt to do something like

```
Public Shared Function GetListAsString(ByVal data As Collection(T)) As String
    Dim retVal As String = "| "
    For Each obj As String In data.ToString()
        retVal = retVal + obj.ToString() + " |"
    Next
    Return retVal
End Function
```

I get an error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: `Error 1 Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.`

Comment: which .Net Framework version do you use? `string.Join("|", list)` already does what you want, at least in .Net Framework 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not get a very helpful error message from the compiler.  You forgot to make the function generic, it cannot produce a decent diagnostic.  Let's focus on the bigger issue:

```
    For Each obj As String In data.ToString()
        retVal = retVal + obj.ToString() + " |"
    Next
```

The For loop is broken, starting with data.ToString().  Just use data.  And the element type of data is T, not String.  Also, since you are only enumerating the collection, you can make do with the lesser interface, IEnumerable<>, making it work on many more collection types.  Thus:

```
Public Shared Function GetCollectionAsString(Of T)(ByVal data As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String
    Dim retVal As String = "| "
    For Each obj As T In data
        retVal = retVal + obj.ToString() + " |"
    Next
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Note the added `(Of T)` after the function name, that's the one that solves your original error message.

Answer (score 3):

`Collection(T)` should be `IEnumerable(Of T)`?

**Update** Btw, Btw, as soon as you want just `ToString` from your collection objects, and `ToString` is defined in class `Object` and all other classes inherit `Object`, you can just use

```
Public Shared Function GetListAsString(ByVal data As IEnumerable(Of Object)) As String
```

Comment: It seemed to like this, let me test it out

Comment: This is your best bet given your goal of making your function work with the widest variety of collections.  `IEnumerable(of T)` works with most (all?) collection classes, including arrays.

Comment: @user489041 I'm not sure, but I think you'll have to add (Of T) to the function declaration, as `Daniel A. White` [suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093936/generics-in-vb-net/7093978#7093978). Can't tell for sure, never tried that personally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the generic on the method signature.

```
Public Shared Function GetListAsString(Of T)(ByVal data As ICollection(Of T)) As String
```

*edit* I changed it.

Comment: I gave this a shot, it gives me a Error Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments. It has the T underlined in `Collection(Of T)`

Comment: `ICollection` is a descendant class of `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable` is suitable for the task, so no need using `ICollection`.

Comment: Sure but he was using `Collection` in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Same solution but with less code thanks to the magic of VB.Net inference:

```
Public Shared Function GetListAsString(Of T)(ByVal data As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String
    Dim retVal = "| "    
    For Each obj In data
        retVal &= obj.ToString + " |"
    Next
    Return retVal
End Function
```

**EDIT**

OR even simpler using String.Join...

```
Public Shared Function GetListAsString(Of T)(ByVal data As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String
    Return "| " & String.Join(" |", data) & " |"
End Function
```

Comment: EDIT: Added a version with String.Join

Answer (score 1):

Shortened version of [Hans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093936/how-do-i-use-generics-in-vb-net/7095469#7095469), with an extension method in place of the explicit `For Each` loop:

```
Public Function GetListAsString(Of T)(ByVal data As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String
    Return data.Aggregate("| ", Function(d, s) d & s.ToString & " |")
End Function
```

But have you tried Snowbear's suggestion from the comments?

```
"| " & String.Join(" | ", data) & " |"
```

This `String.Join` code does give slightly different behaviour from the code in your question, but it's so simple. Here are the differences

```
empty-sequence -> "| |" rather than "| "
1, 2 -> "| 1 | 2 |" rather than "| 1| 2 |" (was that really what you meant?)
```

Comment: Read more about String.Join in this [post](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2011/09/08/c.net-little-wonders-the-string-split-and-join-methods.aspx) on James Michael Hare's excellent blog